# Scrape Price Title Image of product from website

Tags: php, python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, domdocument

Scraping is a new topic for me and I am struggling to understand it. Note: I am using wordpress.

For example, say for my Shoes Blog I want to display a FootLocker product by scraping. How would I extract price, title, and image of a product from 
Footlocker?

From my research, it seems like 
**DOMdocument** in PHP 
or 
Python **BeautifulSoup** 
may be used for this purpose but I am unsure. For my situation (extracting price, title, image) which method will work?

Will DOMdocument work for this? Really need some guidance.

***EDIT***

Here is the specimen html

PRODUCT TITLE

```
<div class="title" data-info="product_title">
<h1 tabindex="698">Jordan Flight Origin 2 - Men's</h1>
</div>
```

PRODUCT PRICE

```
<div class="regular_price">
<span class="label" tabindex="-1"></span>
<span class="value">$114.99</span>
</div>
```

PRODUCT IMAGE

```
<div class="regular_price">
<span class="label" tabindex="-1"></span>
<span class="value">$114.99</span>
</div>
```

PRODUCT URL

http://www.footlocker.com/product/model:234353/sku:05155015/jordan-flight-origin-2-mens/grey/multicolor/?cm=newarrivalsshoessupercat

Comment: Yes BeautifulSoup may help you......Can you please provide the specimen HTML code from where you need to extract data.

Comment: @pyAnna please see my edit. Hopefully I copied the correct html. Does BeautifulSoup make a website run slowly?

Answer (score 0):

```html
import urllib2
import re
result = []
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.footlocker.com/product/model:234353/sku:05155015/jordan-flight-origin-2-mens/grey/multicolor/?cm=newarrivalsshoessupercat')
html = response.read()
m = re.search('<link rel="image_src" href="(.+?)"', html)
if m:
    image = m.group(1)
result.append(image)
m = re.search('<meta name="title" content="(.+?)"', html)
if m:
    product = m.group(1)
result.append(product)
print result
```

I have not used BeautifulSoup and just written a simple code so as to get your work done....hope it works fine, let me know about the changes if required...frankly speaking i never thought of time complexity issues related to BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thanks this helps! But I don't understand... how do you display this data in a Wordpress website? Where would I save your beautifulsoup code? Do I save it in my wordpress theme as a php file?

Comment: @leko frankly speaking i do not have that much idea about Wordpress, maybe Wordpress guys will help you out with the same, post a question regarding the same bro.